# No Checkpoint file found in none

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, bazel

I'm using [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/im2txt) from TensorFlow.

When I run:

```
bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference \
  --checkpoint_path=im2txt/model/train/ \
  --vocab_file=im2txt/data/mscoco/word_counts.txt \
  --input_files=im2txt/data/mscoco/raw-data/man_chair.jpg
```

I get an error:

> No Checkpoint file found in :None

Checking `tf.train.latest_checkpoint` returns None but checkpoint is stored inside `train/`.

Comment: `tf.train.latest_checkpoint` returns none . checkpoint is stored inside /train/

Comment: Have you tried explicit paths from root. Check permissions. Try putting the path in quotes. The README.md shows explicit steps such as setting the paths to environment variables. Maybe try following it more exactly.

Comment: i fixed it.  instead of mentioning the checkpoint directory . i mentioned the file itself directly . its working.

Comment: I tried mentioning the file directly. It is still not working for me.